# Rails 3 fields_for wont assocoiate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, fields-for

In my Rails 3 App, my fields for won't associate, I've been researching and I can't figure out why.

My view:

```
 = form_for(resource, class: 'admin_form', :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name))  do |f|
    = devise_error_messages!
    .admin_form
      ...

      = fields_for :profile do |p|
        ...
        %dl
          %dd
            = f.submit "Sign up", class: "btn"
```

Controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :check_admin_quantity

  def new
    super
  @profile = @user.build_profile
end
```

Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me,     :current_password, :profile_attributes
has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
```

Comment: Could you please explain what `won't associate` means? Also, where do you define `resource`, paste model code and use `f.fields_for` instead of plain `fields_for`.

Comment: What I meant is that the User model portion of the form is created in the data base, but his profile is nil after creation, the fields_for fields weren't associated with the user.  When I use f.fields_for, none of the profile fiends render.  Also, resource is a part of devise and is referring to whatever model devise is associated with, which in this case is the User model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly use `f.fields_for` instead of `fields_for`. The later only creates the fields, but they are not associated with a form object, former is creating fields for associated object.

When you add `f.` you will notice that it is not rendering fields. It is caused by your `resource` not having associated profile. You are building profile on `@user`, but it is different than `resource` object.

If you have a look at default implementation of new, it reads:

```
def new
  build_resource({})
  respond_with self.resource
end
```

you are calling this calling super in your new method. You need to build profile between `build_resource` and `respond_with`, so your `new` action should be:

```
def new
  build_resource({})
  resource.build_profile
  respond_with self.resource
end
```

Comment: This worked, and led me to another issue "Can't mass-assign protected attributes: profile_attributes  :app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:10:in `create'"    I got into the source code on https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb , though I'm not sure how to edit the create action.

Comment: You don't need to, it is error from the model. You need to add `:profile_attributes` to your `attr_accessible` list in `User` model.

Comment: Ah yes, in my trouble shooting I changed that to `:profiles_attributes` and forgot to change it back.  Works like a charm, thanks for your help @BroiSatse